# Heuristic for A* search to collect the maximum number of coins in a 2D grid?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, path-finding, a-star, heuristics

Given the description of an NxM grid (a start cell, a destination cell, unreachable cells, cells that have coins) use the A* path-finding algorithm to traverse the grid from the start cell to the destination cell while **collecting the maximum possible number of coins** with respect to the following constraints:

```
1- Use only horizontal and vertical movement, diagonal movement is not allowed.
2- Each cell can be visited at most once.
3- Each cell can have at most 1 coin.
```

Here is an example (0 denotes an empty cell, 1 denotes a cell with a coin, X denotes an unreachable cell, S is the start cell, D is the destination cell):

**S** , X , X , X , X , X , X , X

**1** , X , X , X , X , X , X , X

**0** , X , X , X , X , X , X , X

**1** , **1** , **1** , X , X , **0** , **1** , **0**

0 , X , **0** , X , X , **0** , X , **0**

0 , X , **0** , **1** , **1** , **1** , X , **1**

0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , **D**

The optimal path cells are **bold**.

Please note that I'm not interested in the actual implementation of the solution, I only want help with finding a suitable heuristic function to model this problem correctly.

Comment: note that in your example there is only one path. You may want to replace the X of the very bottom row by 0 (so your bold path is still prefered against the other path which is shorter but with less 1s)

Comment: There is another path if you notice there is a connection between the bottom of the first column and the third column, however I'll do as told for the sake of simplification, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr; A* and maximizing number of ones: possible but no good

The first problem is defining a proper distance.

Let the state be a position in the grid + the number of picked ones.

The neighbours are trivially the adjacent squares not being `X`

We may pose for distance

```
d(a,b) = -(b.ones - a.ones)
```

- so for the neighbor b, if we pick a 1, the distance is -1
- if no pick then 0

Minimizing d would yield the maximum number of 1.

Regarding the heuristic, to ensure an optimal solution, we need `h` admissible and we may define `h` by
`h(s) = -56` (your grid is 7x8), `h(s) = 56 - s.ones` or even `h(s) = numberOfOnesInTheGrid - s.ones`
(although the later implies we know in advance how many `1s` there are)

**HOWEVER** this is not suitable for A* because:

- we want to explore **all** the paths/states when the goal of A* is to avoid that...
- we expose ourself to cycles (where we would greedily eat until ...long). This is symptomatic and does not happen in shortest path problems (with positive weighted edges) since **cycling** always lead in a longer path being thrown away
- what we want is inherently a longest path problem and not a shortest one (e.g euclidean distance to D vs maximizing the number of 1 (or number of visited states with condition having 1)).

I am afraid A* will not yield satisfactory results. 
A simpler grid (extracted from your example) exhibiting the problem:

```
0 , 1 , 0
0 , X , 0
S , X , 1
0 , 0 , D
```

the upper path is longer (in term of visited squares) but is the optimal one

You can always enforce A* by storing the visited path/states into each state (to avoid cycles) but you may as well just use a dfs with heuristic of taking the neighbours with 1 first